# forge-convert of my local svg does not work?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have a local SVG file that I input into the forge-convert command. I have a free trial of this tool and already set my FORGE_CLIENT_ID and FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET variables (I used the credentials from a web based test app that I created on the forge site).

```
forge-convert "C:\Users\myprofile\Downloads\LocalSVG.svg" --output-folder "C:\Users\myprofile\Downloads\"
```

However this command doesn't appear to generate any gltf, and I notice the following as part of the output message:

`data: { developerMessage: 'The requested resource does not exist.', moreInfo: 'https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/', errorCode: ''`

Is there an example svg that I can use to test this locally? What else could be missing?

Comment: **forge-convert-utils** is made for converting Autodesk SVF format, not SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics)